# distinct on identifier but want to keep only the rows of interest in r

Tags: r, distinct

| identifier | variable |
| --- | --- |
| patient1 | y |
| patient2 | x |
| patient2 | y |
| patient2 | y |
| patient3 | x |
| patient3 | y |

I would like only 1 row per identifier, but for identifiers that have >1 occurence, I would like to keep only the row with variable == "x"

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% arrange(variable != "x") %>% group_by(identifier) %>% slice(1) %>% ungroup()` I sort by `!= x` because FALSE (ie `== "x"`) comes before TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`, you can use `slice_max`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  slice_max(order_by = (variable == 'x'), by = identifier, with_ties = FALSE)

#   identifier variable
# 1   patient1        y
# 2   patient2        x
# 3   patient3        x
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
 slice(match("x", variable, nomatch = 1), .by = identifier)
```

-output

```
   identifier variable
1   patient1        y
2   patient2        x
3   patient3        x
```